# How can I select/mark an item in a list with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to select an item in a DOM draggable list so that I can move it to another field with a button. Is there a `mouseDown` or similar function to mark the selected item?

```
var nmbrCustomers = 10; // Enter the number of customers!
var customerArray = new Array(nmbrCustomers);

for (var i = 1;i < nmbrCustomers + 1; i++){
  customerArray[i] = "f_" + i
}

customerArray.forEach(myFunc);

function myFunc(item,index){
  console.log(document.getElementById(item).innterHTML);
}
```

With this code I can reach all the elements I want, but I don't know how to make them selected/marked. The results from the above code gives the following code for each element:

```
<td class="menuGroup" nowrap="nowrap">
  <img id="someimageID" class="navigatorGroupImage" align="left" 
    src="someimageDir" onclick="toggleGroup(9)" 
    ondragstart="dragStartGroupIcon(event)" alt="Alternar expandir/colapsar">

  <span id="someID" 
    class="navigatorGroupText" draggable="true" 
    onmousedown="mouseDownGroup('f_9', Event.extend(event))" 
    onmouseup="mouseUpGroup('f_9', Event.extend(event))" 
    onmousemove="mouseMoveGroup('f_9', Event.extend(event))" 
    title="someName.">                      
  </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add and remove a CSS class to the dragged element. The following code snippet will work if you add a `draggable` CSS class to the elements you want to drag - change the CSS rule to suit your requirements.

```js
let sources = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

sources.forEach(source => {
  source.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  source.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
});

function dragStart(e) {
  // Add a 'dragging' CSS class to the element
  this.classList.add('dragging');
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  // Remove the 'dragging' CSS class
  this.classList.remove('dragging');
}
```

```css
.dragging {
  opacity: .50;
  border: 6px solid #000;
}
```